# syntax error: unexpected name, expecting )

Tags: arrays, go

I have my code for my BST in GO. I keep getting this error message. I am using noted pad and I am a beginner. 
the error is in my for loop. under the insertList func.

```
type node struct{
    left *node
    right *node
    val int
    }


func insert(tree *node, element int) *node{
    if tree == nil{
        tree = &node{nil, nil, element}
        } else if element > tree.val{
        tree.right = insert( tree.right, element)
        } else if element < tree.val{
        tree.left = insert( tree.left, element)
        }
    return tree
    }
func insertList(elementList []int) *node{
    if tree == nil{
        for i:=0; i<[]int.len; i++{ 
            tree = insert([i]int)}
        return tree}}

func displayBST(tree *node){
    if ( tree != nil) {
        displayBST( tree.left)
        fmt.Println(tree.val)
        displayBST(tree.right)}}


func main(){

     l := [10]int{100, 3, 3, 200, 5, 8, 5, 200, 0, -4}

     s := l[:]

     insertList(s)

     displayBST(insertList(s))

     fmt.Println()}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you past the syntax errors:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type node struct {
    left  *node
    right *node
    val   int
}

func insert(tree *node, element int) *node {
    if tree == nil {
        tree = &node{nil, nil, element}
    } else if element > tree.val {
        tree.right = insert(tree.right, element)
    } else if element < tree.val {
        tree.left = insert(tree.left, element)
    }
    return tree
}

func insertList(tree *node, elementList []int) *node {
    if tree == nil {
        for i := 0; i < len(elementList); i++ {
            tree = insert(tree, elementList[i])
        }
    }
    return tree
}

func displayBST(tree *node) {
    if tree != nil {
        displayBST(tree.left)
        fmt.Println(tree.val)
        displayBST(tree.right)
    }
}

func main() {

    l := [10]int{100, 3, 3, 200, 5, 8, 5, 200, 0, -4}

    s := l[:]

    var t *node

    insertList(t, s)

    displayBST(insertList(t, s))

    fmt.Println()
}
```

Comment: That actually did not work I got more errors. saying tree is undefined. and not enough arguments in call to insert

Comment: @Courtney: That was an earlier version of my answer. Use the current version of my answer.

Comment: I did, that is when I got undefined tree. I need to pass the list of ints into the BST, and the func insertList(elementList []int) was given to me to use...

Comment: hey you were right except for func insertList(elementList[]ints) because in the main method the only argument was the array... thanks